# Breaking HTML table into two different table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to print a table with large number of columns. I came with a solution to break the columns into different table with page break. I wanted to use JQuery for doing that. Here is the HTML, I am new to JQuery, please help me in solving this issue.

## Original HTML structure

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Ami</td>
    <td>35</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>jai</td>
    <td>34</td>
 </tr>
```

## Expected HTML OUTput

```
<html>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Ami</td>
        <td>35</td>
     </tr>

 </table>

 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Ami</td>
        <td>35</td>
     </tr>

 </table>
</html>
```

Is it possible to achieve the expected HTML structure in JQuery.

Comment: And do you want every name to be like that?
Name Age Ami 35
Name Age Jai 34
?

Comment: i think they forgot to code format it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

one possible way:

```
$('<table>').append(
    $('table tr:first-child').clone(), 
    $('table tr').slice(Math.ceil($('table tr').length / 2))
).appendTo('body');
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/HNZ4C/)

---

Version 2:

```
var max = 2; // change this


var $t = $('table');
var $th = $('tr:first-child', $t).remove();
var l = $('tr',$t).length;

while(l > max){
    // extract trs with index larger than max and add them to a new table
    var $trs = $('tr',$t).filter(function(){ return $(this).index() < max; });   
    $('<table/>').append($trs).insertBefore($t);
    l-=max;
}
$('table').each(function(){ $(this).prepend($th.clone()); });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8dV3/)

Comment: Your solution is similar to what I was looking for, except for the fact that I was looking to break the table on the basis of the columns. But, your sample code is the first stepping stone to my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sir ..this code is running and at the same time i am using grid instead of table. How can i resolve this

Comment: And one more suggestion is how can i use page-break after 15 records in the grid ,when printing

Comment: @Sankar hello, what do you mean by grid exactly? I made a modified version which allows to set the number of rows to split. I edited my answer.

Comment: i have a KendoGrid in my application which contains 30 records .when i try to print it became collaplable.i need to fix the print page as 15 records per page ...can u gave me some example as possible